# Constant of a hyperbola

Tags: trigonometry, circles, conic-sections

Hyperbolas are a companion to a circle, sharing many properties when it comes to their trig functions and equation.
But, if the circle has $\pi$ as a constant relation, does a hyperbola have some constant relation as well?

Comment: What do you mean by a "constant relation"?

Comment: $\pi$ is the ratio of the diameter and the circumference. I was wondering if a hyperbola has some similar constant attached to it.

Comment: Up to translation and rotation, one can write any hyperbola in the plane as $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2}$, and the ratio $\lambda = \frac{b}{a}$ is independent of this choice (indeed, the eccentricity $\epsilon$ satisfies $\epsilon^2 = 1 + \lambda^2$). A similar statement holds true for ellipses, but since you're only interested in the analogue with circles, presumably you mean to restrict to the so-called *unit hyperbola*, $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ (and the hyperbolas given by rotating, translating, and dilating this one). By the above these are the hyperbolas with eccentricity $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The only meaningful constant connected to the hyperbola is *e*, but it does not represent a ratio.

Comment: From the point of view of complex numbers, $e$ is related both to circles and hyperbolas (of eccentricity $\sqrt{2}$) in analogous ways, and one gets one from relationship from the other roughly by replacing real numbers with imaginary ones.

Answer (score 1):

Also for an hyperbola there is a link with the number $\pi$, but it can be see only using complex numbers.

The coordinates of a point of a circle of radius $1$ satisfy the equation $ x^2+y^2=1$ and from this we define the trigonometric functions such that $\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta=1$.

From a unit hyperbola of equation $x^2-y^2=1$ we can define ( in a symylar way) the [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) such that $\cosh^2 \theta -\sinh^2 \theta=1$.

Now, using complex numbers we can see that such functions have a nice link with the ''magic'' numbers $\pi$, $i$ and $e$, given by;

$$
\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta=1=e^{2i\pi}
$$
$$
\cosh^2 \theta -\sinh^2 \theta=1=e^{2i\pi}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. This was my thought in college.

A real $ \theta $ makes $ 2 \pi $ in one real rotation by virtue of a real Pythagoras thm

$$
\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta=1=e^{2i\pi}
$$

Since

$ \sin  i \theta =  $i$ \,  \sinh \theta, \cos i \theta = \cosh \theta, $

An imaginary $ i   \theta$  should make a full imaginary rotation by an imaginary version of Pythagoras thm:

$$
\cosh^2 \theta -\sinh^2 \theta=1=e^{2i\pi}.
$$

Comment: I shall delete if  in anyway it is viewed as having  a corrupting effect.